# manipulation after loading non http:// url scheme

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I am trying to create a program that loads an application then can manipulate the application as if it were another UIWebView (a.k.a. I want to execute javascript). I figured this may be possible because you can load it using a webView and a URL scheme. However, I can't seem to manipulate the application at all once it is loaded. This is closely tied to the fact that for http:// schemes webViewDidFinishLoad is being successfully called, but for non http:// schemes webViewDidFinishLoad is not being called..

Here is some of the code I am using:

```
let fb:NSURL! =  NSURL(string:"fb://feed");
webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL:fb));
```

...
The following function is called only on http:// schemes.

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {

    print("hellO");
}
```

Note: It is successfully loading the Facebook feed (but the finished loading method

Comment: Have you tried WKWebView? It's what you should be using for anything new you create.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible.

- For security reasons, iOS apps can not manipulate other apps, like you could with a webpage inside of a web view you controlled.
- For technical reasons, injected JavaScript could not be used to manipulate a typical native iOS app, as most apps are not web-based.

The custom url schemes that iOS apps can provide are only capable of launching the app (switching away from your app; not inside of the web view), and providing functionality published by the other app (such as jumping into Facebook's feed in your example).

`webViewDidFinishLoad` is not being called because iOS is switching from your app to the Facebook app.